# Erro ao filtrar um valor

Tags: php, arraylist

Olá pessoal estou tentando filtrar um valor vindo de um imput usando a função strpos(). 
Esse valor deve ser uma URL e nela deve conter uma pequena string definida por uma lista. Porém não está funcionando o filtro e não consigo encontrar o erro:

```js
<?php
/* VERIFICO SE Há UM POST */
if(count($_POST) > 0) {
 $erro  = array();
 $dados = array();
 
// filtro url ads
$filter_ads = array();
$filter_ads[0] = "galid=";
$filter_ads[1] = "gslid=";
$filter_ads[2] = "ghlid=";
$filter_ads[3] = "gplid=";
$filter_ads[4] = "gulid=";
$filter_ads[5] = "gllid=";
$filter_ads[6] = "gklid=";
$filter_ads[7] = "grlid=";
$filter_ads[8] = "gwlid=";
$filter_ads[9] = "gelid="; 
         

 /* PERCORRO TODOS OS CAMPOS */
 foreach($_POST as $nome => $valor) {

  /* VERIFICO SE NENHUM CAMPO EST?? VAZIO */
  if(isset($valor) || !empty($valor)) {
            // procura por campo URL e verifica se foi digitado corretamente
            if($nome == 'link1' && !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$valor)) {
                //Filtro o valor digitado
                foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
                    if (strpos($valor, $filter)){
                        echo "Aceito";
                    } else {
                    $erro[$nome]  = 'A <strong>URL</strong> inserida é inválida.';
                    }
                }
            }
                                                                            
            // Insere os valores removendo todas as tags HTML e espaços em branco inseridas no começo e fim do valor
            $dados[$nome] = trim(strip_tags($valor));
  } else {
    $erro[$nome] = "<span style='color:red;'>O campo <strong>".ucwords($nome)."</strong> n?o pode ficar vazio</span>"; 
   }
  }
 }
 
 // verifico se há algum erro
 if(count($erro) == 0) {
        $hostname = "localhost";
        $usuario = "user_up";
        $senha = "123456";
        $DB = "user_teste";
                
  $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $usuario, $senha);
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die('Falha ao estabelecer uma conex??o com o banco de dados: '.$conn->connect_error);
  } else {
  
   // VERIFICO SE EXISTE o BANCO DE DADOS, CASO n?o, ? criado automaticamente.
   if(!$conn->select_db($DB)) {
    $conn->query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' .$DB. ';');
    $conn->select_db($DB);
   }
   
            // faz o mesmo com a tabela
   $tabela = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'introads\'');
   if($tabela->num_rows == 0) {
    $conn->query(
     "CREATE table introads(
      id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
      link1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
     );"
    );
   }
   
   $campos  = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
   $valores = implode("','", $dados);
   $valores = "'".$valores."'";   
   
   $conn->query("INSERT INTO introads(".$campos.") VALUES (".$valores.")");
   // SE TUDO ESTIVER OK, REDIRECIONO PARA UMA P??GINA DE SUCESSO
   header('location:index.php');
   
  }
 }
 
}
?>

<form id="introAds" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<ul>
 <li id='block1'>
     <input type="text" name="link1" lang="pt" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo isset($dados['link1']) ? $dados['link1'] : ''; ?>"  />
        <?php if(isset($erro['link1'])) { ?>
            <label class="erro" for="nome"><?php echo $erro['link1']; ?></label> 
  <?php } ?>
    </li>

    <li>
<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Gravar" />
    </li>           
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: como é enviado o POST? poste o código do formulário que envia os valores do POST. E qual o resultado que está acontecendo?

Comment: Onde está "//filtra o valor digitado" deveria retornar "Aceito" como true ou "A URL inserida é inválida" para false, mas não resulta nenhum dos dois.

Comment: Preciso que o script pega o valor do campo que é uma URL e verifica se algum elemento da lista filtro está contido na URL, se sim retorna "Aceito" se não retorna "A URL inserida é inválida" . A validação do formulário tá ok e a inserção dos dados no banco de dados também. Só o filtro que está com problema.

Answer (score 1):

Identifiquei 2 problemas no seu código.

1) Como a identação estava confusa (pelo menos quando copiei seu código e colei no Netbeans ele ficou meio estranho), você acabou deixando uma `}` a mais.

2) Você está negando uma condição verdadeira. No if em que você valida se o campo link1 existe e se foi digitado uma url com o preg_match, você colocou um `!` na frente do preg_match. Isso esta validando o seguinte:

> Se $nome for igual a 'link1' e o $valor NÃO for uma URL, faça:

Segue abaixo script com as correções:

OBS: acrescentei um `$_POST = '...'` no início apenas para testar. Dentro do if que trata o erro coloquei um `die()` apenas para testar. Quando for usar o script, retire essas 2 linhas

```
<?php
/* VERIFICO SE Há UM POST */
//depois de testar, remova essa variável.
$_POST['link1'] = 'http://www.google.com.br?galid=5';

if(count($_POST) > 0) {

    $erro  = array();
    $dados = array();

    // filtro url ads
    $filter_ads = array();
    $filter_ads[0] = "galid=";
    $filter_ads[1] = "gslid=";
    $filter_ads[2] = "ghlid=";
    $filter_ads[3] = "gplid=";
    $filter_ads[4] = "gulid=";
    $filter_ads[5] = "gllid=";
    $filter_ads[6] = "gklid=";
    $filter_ads[7] = "grlid=";
    $filter_ads[8] = "gwlid=";
    $filter_ads[9] = "gelid="; 


    /* PERCORRO TODOS OS CAMPOS */
    foreach($_POST as $nome => $valor) {

        /* VERIFICO SE NENHUM CAMPO EST?? VAZIO */
        if(isset($valor) || !empty($valor)) {
            // procura por campo URL e verifica se foi digitado corretamente
            if($nome == 'link1' && preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$valor)) {
                //Filtro o valor digitado
                foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
                    if (strpos($valor, $filter)){
                        echo "Aceito";
                    } else {
                        $erro[$nome]  = 'A <strong>URL</strong> inserida é inválida.';
                    }
                }
            }

            // Insere os valores removendo todas as tags HTML e espaços em branco inseridas no começo e fim do valor
            $dados[$nome] = trim(strip_tags($valor));
        } else {
            $erro[$nome] = "<span style='color:red;'>O campo <strong>".ucwords($nome)."</strong> n?o pode ficar vazio</span>";  
        }
    }

    // verifico se há algum erro
    if(count($erro) == 0) {
        //depois de testar remova o die()
        die("ENTREI PARA TRATAR O ERRO");

        $hostname = "localhost";
        $usuario = "user_up";
        $senha = "123456";
        $DB = "user_teste";

        $conn = new mysqli($hostname, $usuario, $senha);
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die('Falha ao estabelecer uma conex??o com o banco de dados: '.$conn->connect_error);
        } else {

            // VERIFICO SE EXISTE o BANCO DE DADOS, CASO n?o, ? criado automaticamente.
            if(!$conn->select_db($DB)) {
                $conn->query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ' .$DB. ';');
                $conn->select_db($DB);
            }

            // faz o mesmo com a tabela
            $tabela = $conn->query('SHOW TABLES LIKE \'introads\'');
            if($tabela->num_rows == 0) {
                $conn->query(
                            "CREATE table introads(
                                id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, 
                                link1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
                                PRIMARY KEY (id)
                            );"
                            );
            }

            $campos  = implode(", ", array_keys($dados));
            $valores = implode("','", $dados);
            $valores = "'".$valores."'";            

            $conn->query("INSERT INTO introads(".$campos.") VALUES (".$valores.")");
            // SE TUDO ESTIVER OK, REDIRECIONO PARA UMA P??GINA DE SUCESSO
            header('location:index.php');

        }
    }

}
?>

<form id="introAds" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<ul>
    <li id='block1'>
        <input type="text" name="link1" lang="pt" maxlength="400" value="<?php echo isset($dados['link1']) ? $dados['link1'] : ''; ?>"  />
        <?php if(isset($erro['link1'])) { ?>
            <label class="erro" for="nome"><?php echo $erro['link1']; ?></label>    
        <?php } ?>
    </li>

    <li>
<input type="submit" id="enviar" value="Gravar" />
    </li>           
</ul>
</form>
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Thomas a sua ajuda foi de suma importância, pois eu estava quebrando a cabeça nesses dois erros simples na condição, porém o problema ainda não estava aí. Sabe por quê?
Essa condição de validação de email é para cancelar a operação se o email for inválido e não insere os valores no banco de dados. Então pensei mais um pouco e percebi que o filtro deveria ficar fora dessa condição para que seja lançada os dados. Agora deu certo. Veja como ficou:

```js
<?php
/* PERCORRO TODOS OS CAMPOS */
 foreach($_POST as $nome => $valor) {

  /* VERIFICO SE NENHUM CAMPO EST?? VAZIO */
  if(isset($valor) || !empty($valor)) {
            // procura por campo URL e verifica se foi digitado corretamente
            if($nome == 'link1' && !preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i", $valor)) {
                $erro[$nome]  = 'A <strong>URL</strong> inserida é inválida.';
            }
            
            $item = "negado";        
            foreach ($filter_ads as $filter) {
                if (strpos($valor, $filter)){
                    $item = "permitido";               
                }
            }  
            
            if($item == "permitido") {    
                // Insere os valores removendo todas as tags HTML e espaços em branco inseridas no começo e fim do valor
                $dados[$nome] = trim(strip_tags($valor)); 
            } else {
                $erro[$nome]  = "Há endereços invalidos. Por favor repita o processo em todos os campos navamente.";
            }
            
  } else {
            $erro[$nome] = "O campo ".ucwords($nome)." não pode ficar vazio"; 
  }
 }
?>
```

Valeu pela força

Comment: Maravilha =) !!!